# pear on CentOS with "No Package" message

Tags: centos, php, pear

I googled for hours to find a solution but couldn't find anything.

What can I do with this error? I couldn't install php-pear on centOS 6.5.

```
[root@server ~] # yum search php-pear
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hosttile
* base: www.mirrorservice.org
* epel: www.mirrorservice.org
* extras: mirror.econdc.com
* rpmforge: www.mirrorserv1ce:org
* updates: centos.hyve.com
============================ Matched: php-pear =========================
horde-enhanced.noarch : Adds extra functionality to the horde framework

[root@server ~]# yum install php-pear
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: wvv.mirrorservice.org
* epel: www.mirrorserv1ce:org
* extras: mirror.econdc.com
* rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
* updates: centos.openitc.uk
Setting up Install Process
No package php—pear available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After days finally I could find the answer.

Just type:

```
sudo nano /etc/yum.conf
```

And then remove php*

then type:

```
yum install --enablerepo remi php-pear php-devel
```

Good luck!

Comment: Which is basically the same as Michael Hampton's recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Check your yum configuration to learn if the packages have been excluded. Yum cannot install excluded packages, and will not even acknowledge their existence.

The most obvious files to inspect are:

- `/etc/yum.conf`
- Each file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely in the base repo (see below from a Cent 6.5 machine).  I would try a `yum clean all` first to eliminate the possibility of a caching issue.

```
[gbeech@ny-man02 ~]$ yum info php-pear
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: yum.ds.stackexchange.com
stack-local-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00
Available Packages
Name        : php-pear
Arch        : noarch
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.9.4
Release     : 4.el6
Size        : 393 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : PHP Extension and Application Repository framework
URL         : http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR
License     : BSD and PHP and LGPLv2+
Description : PEAR is a framework and distribution system for reusable PHP
            : components.  This package contains the basic PEAR components.

[gbeech@ny-man02 ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
[gbeech@ny-man02 ~]$
```